# Why using COUNT with SELF JOIN gives different result value

Tags: t-sql, join, count

Can somebody explain me why if I use SELF JOIN and COUNT it gives me different result than just using COUNT command?
Same table with `ControlNo` column. The value in a column is NOT Unique. 
This query gives me total counts `15586`.

```
    select  (Select  COUNT(ControlNo) 
                from tblQuotes Q1 
                where Q1.ControlNo = a.ControlNo
            ) QuotedTotal
    FROM    tblQuotes a 
   inner join  lstlines l on a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
   where    l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2016
```

[image]

But then, if I run this query it gives me total counts of `15095`.

```
select  COUNT(ControlNo) as QuotedTotal
from    tblQuotes a
inner join  lstlines l on a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
  where     l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2016
```

[image]

What exactly changing the total amount and why? 
And why would I use the first scenario?
And is any way to modify the first query to get the sum of `15586` without breaking down by each row?
Thank you

Comment: It would help if you share the tables structure first of all. Is `ControlNo` a unique field? It seems there are some rows in `tblQuotes` which share the value in the `ControlNo` field but not all of them join against the `lstlines` table. Do you need to count those as well or not?

Comment: Column `ControlNo` is not unique, which is probably why the result is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because field `ControlNo` is not unique and there are some records sharing that value, although not all of them join against the `lstlines` table with that condition. So basically your last query does:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.ControlNo)
FROM lstlines l
INNER JOIN tblQuotes a ON a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
WHERE l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2016
```

While the first one basically does:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.ControlNo)
FROM lstlines l
INNER JOIN tblQuotes a ON a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
INNER JOIN tblQuotes b ON a.ControlNo = b.ControlNo
WHERE l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2016
```

As you can see, in this second query you are not only counting the rows that match your `lstlines` table, but also all the rows in `tblQuotes` which have the same `ControlNo` as those who match against `lstlines`.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do by chance these queries return the same numbers you get with your queries?

Comment: No, they do not return the same numbers. Thats how it should be, correct?

Comment: No, I mean that my first query returns 15095 and the second one 15586, like your two queries.

Comment: Oh yes. It does. So its all correct. 
Thanks again for the explanation.